# NodeEntity not recognized when SessionFactory is created inside library

Tags: classpath, neo4j-ogm, classgraph

I am not sure if my problem is a non-existent feature or I am using the *neo4j-ogm* framework incorrectly. Since you are only supposed to post bugs or feature requests in the projects GitHub repository, I would like to place my question here first.

Please be aware, that I shortened my real code to just give you an idea what I try to achieve.

My example application consists of two modules:
**Module a** contains a class to create *neo4j-ogm* sessions. There I read the configuration from a property file and create the session factory, passing the packages to scan as parameters:

```
public Neo4jController(final String ... packagesWithNodes) {
    ConfigurationSource props = new ClasspathConfigurationSource("neo4jogm.properties");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(props).build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, packagesWithNodes);
    ...
}
```

**Module b** includes *module a* as a Maven dependency and then tries to persist a `NodeEntity` via the `Session` object. The `Session` is created correctly, but the `NodeEntity` in the passed package is not recognized.

```
public MyObject create(final MyObject newObject) {
  Neo4jController neo4jController = new Neo4jController("my.example.package");
  neo4jController.getNeo4jSession().save(newObject);

  ...
}
```

This always results in an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Class class my.example.package.MyObject is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.
```

This is what my `NodeEntity` in *module b* looks like

```
package my.example.package;

import de.bitandgo.workflow.common.model.Neo4jNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;

@NodeEntity(label = "MyObject")
public class MyObject extends Neo4jNode {

  @Property
  public String name;
}
```

The base class contains among others

```
public abstract class Neo4jNode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

I know that *neo4j-ogm* uses **glassgraph** internally for scanning the classpath. The corresponding call in the framework with prepended configuration looks like this:

```
private static List<String> useClassgraph(String[] packagesOrClasses) {

    // .enableExternalClasses() is not needed, as the super classes are loaded anywhere when the class is loaded.
    try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph()
        .ignoreClassVisibility()
        .acceptPackages(packagesOrClasses)
        .acceptClasses(packagesOrClasses)
        .scan()) {
        return scanResult.getAllClasses().getNames();
    }
}
```

Via debugging I verified that the desired package `my.example.package` was passed as an argument to the `GlassGraph` object.

Also the `Neo4jController` in *module a* is able to load the class. I have tested this with the following code

```
try {
  Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("my.example.package.MyObject");
  System.out.println(aClass);  // prints "class my.example.package.MyObject"
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
```

My question is whether *neo4j-ogm*/*classgraph* may not be able to find the class at all due to the way *neo4j-ogm* uses *classgraph*, or if I am doing something wrong in the usage.

**Update 1:**
The problem seems to be related to my application running inside an application server (TomEE). When I deploy my application *ClassGraph* is not able to find the configured package.
But executing the exact same scan via a classical `main` method finds me the expected class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph()
                .ignoreClassVisibility()
                .acceptPackages("my.example.package")
                .acceptClasses()
                .scan()) {
            System.out.println(scanResult.getAllClasses().getNames());
        }
    }
```

So I assume the problem is related to the compiled classes not being visible in the "normal" classpath when deploying the application into an application server?

I appreciate any input.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed related to the **glassgraph** library, which is used by *neo4j-ogm* for scanning the class path for model files.

**glassgraph** supports a wide variety of classloaders, but the one of *TomEE* wasn't included yet. This problem has been fixed since version 4.8.107, so if you run into a similar problem check whether **glassgraph** supports the classloader of the application server used by you.

You can easily overwrite *neo4j-ogm*'s classgraph dependency by specifying the version you need in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- overwriting the internal classloader of neo4j-ogm because it's used version does not support ApacheTomEE -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
  <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.107</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem was not related to my multi module Maven structure.